# Is it safe to clean temporary files produced by Hudson?

Tags: linux, cleaning, temporary-files, hudson

I tried to clean this directory in my vitural machine:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local Settings\Temp
```

However, this VM is a Hudson Slave, and I found it full with directories of this kind: **hudson-remoting57575653437742745725**

and which contains such a tree: **hudson-remoting57575653437742745725\com\sun\jna\win32-x86**

and the final directory contains this dll: `jnidispatch.dll`

Is it safe to delete these kind of directories?

If it is safe to delete clean Temp directory, when can I include the **cleaning action** in a script that would be compiled *by a Hudson job*? At the end of the script *or* at the begining?

Answer (score 0):

jnidispatch is a Java Native Library, so I would say 'NO' on that.

The others(s), I would recommend that you not delete them if you have no real need to delete them.  If you want to delete them for no particular reason, then I would say leave them be.  If there is an immediate threat, then delete them, but make sure you do proper backing up.

Comment: by saying "NO" , do you mean it is NOT say? Well, I need to empty the tmp directory for saving VM space reason.

Comment: I mean that is probably not safe, and could cause errors to your Java.